# How did the answer find the antiderivative to this function? (Lebesgue integration)

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, laplace-transform

I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754135/application-of-fubini-tonellis-theorem-on-function-frac2-pie-ax-cosx) earlier. I was wondering how did the answer found the antiderivative of $\frac{a}{a^2+\cos^2x}$ to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\tan^{-1}(\frac{a \tan x}{\sqrt{1+a^2}})$?

I have not done Laplce transform previously and so is this purely by Laplace transform? I could verify that this is indeed the anti-derivative but could we get around Laplace transform to find the antiderivative straightaway?

Comment: What does the integral have to do with Lebesgue integration? As a hint to solve the integral let $\tan x=t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the integrand has only even powers of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, the substitution $z=\tan x$ can be useful:
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{\alpha}{\alpha^2+\cos^2x}dx&=\int\frac{\alpha dz}{\alpha^2+1+\alpha^2z^2}=\int\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\\
&=\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}+C=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\alpha z}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}+C\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\alpha\tan x}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}+C\end{align}$$
Where we have made the further substitution $\alpha z=\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}\tan\theta$