# Question on Laplace Transform of a Bessel Integral of the First Kind

Tags: physics, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

I am trying to understand an integral I saw in a book. The book is "Earth Resistances" by G.F. Tagg. Unfortunately it's difficult to get a hold of this book, but I am confused by equation 3.9 is in chapter 3 of the book. I will put what I think is necessary in this but if anyone feels as though there is missing information please tell me.

The following equation is for the potential measured at the surface given a model of the earth that has 2 soil layers of different resistivity. The following equation focuses on only the part that I am stuck on.

$$V_1 = \int_0^\infty \left[\frac{2ke^{-2\lambda h}}{1 - ke^{-2\lambda h}}\right] J_0(\lambda r) d\lambda$$
The fraction inside of the brackets is then expanded into it's geometric series:
$$\frac{2ke^{-2\lambda h}}{1 - ke^{-2\lambda h}} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} k^n e^{-2n\lambda h}$$
This yields
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} k^n e^{-2n\lambda h} J_0(\lambda r) d\lambda = 2\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{k^n}{\sqrt{r^2 + (2nk)^2}}$$
It's the last equivalence that is confusing me. I cant find a Laplace transform that has the same form as the RHS. The one I can find is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326778/laplace-transform-of-the-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind), which as far as I can tell doesn't reduce into the RHS equation. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be $\sqrt{r^2 + (2nh)^2}$ on the right side, not $\sqrt{r^2 + (2nk)^2}$.

$$ \int_0^\infty \exp(-p \lambda) J_0(r \lambda)\; d\lambda = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+r^2}}$$
if $p, r > 0$.  Take $p = 2 n h$.